# How to round a integer to the close hundred?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I don't know it my nomenclature is correct! Anyway, these are the integer I have, for example :

```
76
121
9660
```

And I'd like to round them to the close hundred, such as they must become :

```
100
100
9700
```

How can I do it faster in C#? I think about an algorithm, but maybe there are some utilities on C#?

Comment: @RoyDictus He has tried StackOverflow!

Comment: @HaLaBi : hahaha! Yeah, I was trying with close @L.B solution (he delete the post, dunno : `var newi = (int)Math.Round(oldi / 100d)*100;`). I think this is the best way...

Comment: @markzzz What about 50? 0 or 100?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try the `Math.Round` method. Here's how:

```
Math.Round(76d / 100d, 0) * 100;
Math.Round(121d / 100d, 0) * 100;
Math.Round(9660d / 100d, 0) * 100;
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution to comprehend from the lot. +1! You dont require the overload to specify `0` though. May be you could use midpoint rounding overload better

Comment: Use decimal, not double for this.

Comment: I don't think this is working in the way most people expect! `Math.Round` will truncate the value so `Math.Round(50d / 100d, 0)` will be 0. Some people might expect it to be 100.

Comment: When you expect that 50/100 rounds to one, you can use the `Math.Round(decimal d, int decimals, MidpointRounding mode)` overload:    
`Math.Round(50d / 100d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: Oh. I just saw that @JimAho added an answer to this question that shows how to use the `MidpointRounding` enum (http://stackoverflow.com/a/36421665/964821)

Comment: In VB.NET: `Math.Round(num / 100) * 100`. Not entirely sure what the "d" stands for.

Answer (score 28):

Try this expression:

```
(n + 50) / 100 * 100
```

**Caveat:** only works for non-negative `n`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The question asked about integers.

Comment: Incorrect for negative n. n=-99 rounds to 0 rather than -100.

Comment: @LeonFrickenschmidt Good point. Updated.

Answer (score 27):

I wrote a simple extension method to generalize this kind of rounding a while ago:

```
public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static int Round(this int i, int nearest)
    {
        if (nearest <= 0 || nearest % 10 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("nearest", "Must round to a positive multiple of 10");

        return (i + 5 * nearest / 10) / nearest * nearest;
    }
}
```

It leverages integer division to find the closest rounding.

Example use:

```
int example = 152;
Console.WriteLine(example.Round(100)); // round to the nearest 100
Console.WriteLine(example.Round(10)); // round to the nearest 10
```

And in your example:

```
Console.WriteLine(76.Round(100)); // 100
Console.WriteLine(121.Round(100)); // 100
Console.WriteLine(9660.Round(100)); // 9700
```

Comment: What would give for `51.Round(-10)` ?

Comment: @L.B I tested it and it gave me 40.

Comment: It would throw a `UseYourCommonSense` exception.

Comment: @JasonLarke Thanks! Also, what is it called then you use `this int i` for the first parameter. That's a new trick I learned from this answer.

Comment: @GisMofx It's called an `Extension Method` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/bb383977.aspx they're quite handy.

Answer (score 11):

Just some addition to [@krizzzn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964821/krizzzn)'s accepted answer...

Do note that the following will return 0:

```
Math.Round(50d / 100d, 0) * 100;
```

Consider using the following and make it return 100 instead:

```
Math.Round(50d / 100d, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100;
```

Depending on what you're doing, using decimals might be a better choice (note the **m**):

```
Math.Round(50m / 100m, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 100m;
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old thread. I wrote a new method. Hope this will be useful for some one.

```cs
        public static double Round(this float value, int precision)
        {
            if (precision < -4 && precision > 15)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("precision", "Must be and integer between -4 and 15");

            if (precision >= 0) return Math.Round(value, precision);
            else
            {
                precision = (int)Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(precision));
                value = value + (5 * precision / 10);
                return Math.Round(value - (value % precision), 0);
            }
        }
```

Example:

```cs
    float value = 6666.677777F;
    Console.Write(value.Round(2)); //6666.68
    Console.Write(value.Round(0)); //6667
    Console.Write(value.Round(-2)); //6700
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi i write this extension this gets the next hundred for each number you pass

```
/// <summary>
    /// this extension gets the next hunfìdred for any number you whant
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i">numeber to rounded</param>
    /// <returns>the next hundred number</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// eg.:
    /// i =   21 gets 100
    /// i =  121 gets 200
    /// i =  200 gets 300
    /// i = 1211 gets 1300
    /// i = -108 gets -200
    /// </remarks>
    public static int RoundToNextHundred(this int i)
    {
        return i += (100 * Math.Sign(i) - i % 100);
        //use this line below if you want RoundHundred not NEXT
        //return i % 100 == byte.MinValue? i : i += (100 * Math.Sign(i) - i % 100);
    }

    //and for answer at title point use this algoritm
    var closeHundred = Math.Round(number / 100D)*100;

    //and here the extension method if you prefer

    /// <summary>
    /// this extension gets the close hundred for any number you whant
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">number to be rounded</param>
    /// <returns>the close hundred number</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// eg.:
    /// number =   21 gets    0
    /// number =  149 gets  100
    /// number =  151 gets  200
    /// number = -149 gets -100
    /// number = -151 gets -200
    /// </remarks>
    public static int RoundCloseHundred(this int number)
    {
        return (int)Math.Round(number / 100D) * 100;
    }
```

Comment: This algorithm does not actually round, but it searches for the next value where `value % 100 == 0`, e.g. when this method is called with i = 200, then it returns 300.

Comment: And it does not work for negative values: when this method is called with i = -4, then it returns 100, although I would expect 0.

Comment: That's not how rounding works - when I already have a value of 200, then it should not be rounded to 300 (because 200 already is a quantized value of the rounding scale).

If you do normal integer rounding, then you also would not expect the following statement to be true: Math.Round(1) == 2

Comment: I insert the negative number , now if you insert a negative number this gets the next negative hundred

Comment: Keep in mind the method is called Round NEXT Hundred not RoundHundred.
in the second way you are right, but 300 is the NEXT hundred  of 200

Comment: I added the RoundHundred fo feO2x

Comment: Again, this is not how rounding works - even if the name indicates that your method is not performing as expected. The OP clearly asked for a rounding solution in his question.

Comment: @luka OP asked for closest hundred, not next hundred. By your logic, this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: the last line is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to round integer numbers up (as the OP actually did), then you can resort to this solution:

```
public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static int RoundUpTo(this int number, int nearest)
    {
        if (nearest < 10 || nearest % 10 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(nearest), $"{nameof(nearest)} must be a positive multiple of 10, but you specified {nearest}.");

        int modulo = number % nearest;
        return modulo == 0 ? number : modulo > 0 ? number + (nearest - modulo) : number - modulo;
    }
}
```

If you want to perform floating-point (or decimal) rounding, then resort to the answers of @krizzzn and @Jim Aho.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 9660;
int remainder = num % 100;
Console.WriteLine(remainder < 50 ? num - remainder : num + (100 -remainder));
```

Note: I haven't tested this thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar project internally where the business requirements were to search within the 100's range of a given number and find duplicate DB records.  So if the user was using line 856 I would search 800 - 899.  If the user was using 8567 I would search 8500 - 8599.  Not an exact rounding by 100's, but thought I would include my unique approach as some of these basic coding questions are embedded within a larger business project.  To test this I seeded a decimal list from 1 - 99999 and spit the results out into a file.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method accepts an inbound Line Number and returns the line range
    /// in the form of lowest to highest based on 100's
    /// Example would be 9122 returns 9100 - 9199
    /// It's used for generating some additional BOM Temp functionality.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inboundNumber"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ProjectLineRange CalculateLineRange(decimal inboundNumber)
    {
        var lineRange = new ProjectLineRange();
        var numberLength = inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Length;

        switch (numberLength)
        {
            case 0: //NULL?
                break;
            case 1: //Represents 1 - 9
                lineRange.LineBottom = 1;
                lineRange.LineTop = 99;
                break;
            case 2: //Represents 10 - 99
                lineRange.LineBottom = 1;
                lineRange.LineTop = 99;
                break;
            case 3: //Represents 100 - 999
                lineRange = CalculateHundredsRange((int)(inboundNumber / 100));
                break;
            case 4: //Represents 1000 - 9999
                lineRange = CalculateThousandsRange(
                    Convert.ToInt32(inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1, 1)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(0, 1)));
                break;
            case 5: //Represents 10000 - 99999
                lineRange = CalculateTenThousandsRange(
                    Convert.ToInt32(inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(2, 1)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(1, 1)),
                    Convert.ToInt32(inboundNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Substring(0, 1)));
                break;
        }

        return lineRange;
    }

public class ProjectLineRange
    {
       public decimal LineBottom { get; set; }
       public decimal LineTop { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to return the range for the 100's place
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hundredsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ProjectLineRange CalculateHundredsRange(int hundredsPlaceValue)
    {
        var tempLineRange = new ProjectLineRange();
        tempLineRange.LineBottom = hundredsPlaceValue * 100;
        tempLineRange.LineTop = tempLineRange.LineBottom + 99;

        return tempLineRange;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to return the range for the 100's place when factoring a 1000's number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hundredsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <param name="thousandsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ProjectLineRange CalculateThousandsRange(int hundredsPlaceValue, int thousandsPlaceValue)
    {
        var tempLineRange = new ProjectLineRange();
        var tempThousands = thousandsPlaceValue * 1000;
        var hundredsRange = CalculateHundredsRange(hundredsPlaceValue);
        tempLineRange.LineBottom = tempThousands + hundredsRange.LineBottom;
        tempLineRange.LineTop = tempThousands + hundredsRange.LineTop;

        return tempLineRange;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method to return the range for the 100's place when factoring a 10000's number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hundredsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <param name="thousandsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <param name="tenThousandsPlaceValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ProjectLineRange CalculateTenThousandsRange(int hundredsPlaceValue, int thousandsPlaceValue, int tenThousandsPlaceValue)
    {
        var tempLineRange = new ProjectLineRange();
        var tempThousands = thousandsPlaceValue * 1000;
        var tempTenThousands = tenThousandsPlaceValue * 10000;
        var hundredsRange = CalculateHundredsRange(hundredsPlaceValue);
        tempLineRange.LineBottom = tempTenThousands + tempThousands + hundredsRange.LineBottom;
        tempLineRange.LineTop = tempTenThousands + tempThousands + hundredsRange.LineTop;

        return tempLineRange;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern .NET equivalent generic method for rounding whatever number to the nearest whatever multiple.

```
/// <summary>
/// Translate <paramref name="toTranslate">the provided 
/// value</paramref> to the nearest multiple of 
/// <paramref name="nearestMultipleOf">the provided 
/// multiplier</paramref>, using "away from zero" midpoint 
/// rounding, also known by this library as "normal" rounding.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="toTranslate">The number whose value will 
/// be translated to the nearest multiple of 
/// <paramref name="nearestMultipleOf"/> to produce the 
/// result.</param>
/// <param name="nearestMultipleOf">The value that the 
/// result will be a multiple of and is the nearest 
/// multiple of this value to <paramref name="toTranslate"/> 
/// when employing "away from zero" or "normal" midpoint 
/// rounding.</param>
/// <returns><paramref name="toTranslate">The provided 
/// value</paramref> translated to the nearest multiple 
/// of <paramref name="nearestMultipleOf"/>
/// using "away from zero" or "normal" midpoint rounding.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">This occurs if 
/// <paramref name="nearestMultipleOf"/> is less than zero.</exception>
public static TNumber ToNearestMultiple<TNumber>(this TNumber toTranslate, 
TNumber nearestMultipleOf) where TNumber : INumberBase<TNumber>
{
    if (nearestMultipleOf == TNumber.Zero) return TNumber.Zero;
    
    if (TNumber.IsNegative(nearestMultipleOf)) 
        throw new ArgumentException($"The provided value must be " 
        + "greater than or equal to zero.", nameof(nearestMultipleOf));

    double nearestMultipleOfAsADouble = Convert.ToDouble(nearestMultipleOf),
        toTranslateAsDouble = Convert.ToDouble(toTranslate),
        fraction = toTranslateAsDouble / nearestMultipleOfAsADouble,
        roundedFraction = fraction.RoundNormal(0);
    
    double scaled = roundedFraction * nearestMultipleOfAsADouble;
    TNumber scaledAsInt = (TNumber)Convert.ChangeType(scaled, typeof(TNumber));
    return scaledAsInt;
}
```

Tests:

```
Assert.AreEqual(10, 7.ToNearestMultiple(10));
Assert.AreEqual(7, 6.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(7, 7.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(7, 8.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(7, 9.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(7, 10.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 11.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 12.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 13.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 14.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 15.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 16.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(14, 17.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(21, 18.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(21, 19.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(21, 20.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(21, 21.ToNearestMultiple(7));
Assert.AreEqual(21, 22.ToNearestMultiple(7));

Assert.AreEqual(0, 22.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(50, 25.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(50, 37.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(50, 74.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(100, 75.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(100, 90.ToNearestMultiple(50));
Assert.AreEqual(100, 100.ToNearestMultiple(50));

Assert.AreEqual(22.2, Math.Round(22.6.ToNearestMultiple(7.4), 10));

Assert.AreEqual(-20, -15.ToNearestMultiple(10));
Assert.AreEqual(-10, -14.ToNearestMultiple(10));

Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentException>(() => 15.ToNearestMultiple(-10));
Assert.AreEqual(0, 10.ToNearestMultiple(0));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class Maths
{
    public static int Round(this int value, int precision)
    {
        var coef = Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(precision));
        var x = (int)Math.Round(value / coef, 0);
        return x * (int)coef;
    }
}
```

var number = 34569;

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(0));//34569

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(1));//34570

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(2));//34600

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(3));//35000

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(4));//30000

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(5));//    0

Debug.WriteLine(number.Round(6));//    0