# Math.Round in vb.net not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, rounding

I have this number : `666872700` i need to round it to be : `666900000`

I used : `Math.Round(666872700,4)` but this is not working 
Is there any easy way in vb.net I can use other than dividing by `100000` then rounding then multiplying by `100000` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Math.Round` clearly states:

> Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to a specified number of **fractional digits**.

So it rounds stuff behind the decimal separator, but not integral part. I know of no other way than dividing, rounding and then multiplying again.

---

If you know a little C#, you can use the following extension method Jason Larke wrote in his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153757/117362). I don't know whether it works, but you should be able to translate it to VB.NET and try it:

```
public static class MathExtensions
{
    public static int Round(this int i, int nearest)
    {
        if (nearest <= 0 || nearest % 10 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("nearest", "Must round to a positive multiple of 10");

        return (i + 5 * nearest / 10) / nearest * nearest;
    }
}
```

Comment: so math.round is used just for decimal numbers ?

Comment: this function will round the specific digit but it keep the numbers after it as they are and will not turn them into 0

Comment: Yes, `Math.Round` is for decimals. And no, the method (I just tried it with your numbers) works as expected.